# Cardinality bounds on set algebra

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computer-science, cardinals, upper-lower-bounds

Assume two sets $A$ and $B$. Consider the following set of inequalities:

- $\max \left(\lvert A \rvert, \lvert B\rvert \right) \le \lvert A \cup B\rvert \le \lvert A \rvert + \lvert B \rvert $
- $\lvert A \cap B\rvert \le \min\left(\lvert A \rvert, \lvert B \rvert \right)$

I'm looking for a **text reference** that discusses and proves them and that may include **more cardinality bounds** on these and other set operations. I'm particularly interested in both math and CS research that may derive a tighter set of bounds on set unions and intersections.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those inequalites are not hard to prove for a person interested in math.  That tighter bounds are not possible can be shown by example.
Also not hard to prove is:

$$|A \cup B| + |A \cap B| = |A| + |B|.  $$

Comment: Thanks do any/all of these inequalities have a name?